# How to find the proportion of zones for each neighbourhood using psql?

Tags: psql

I have a table with Neighbourhood, Zones and Lot size. How to find the proportion of zones in Each neighbourhood using Lot size ??

This is my table:

```
Neighbourhood    Zones    Lotsize
Albany           RSL      415
Albany           RSL      410
Albany           PU       34621
Abbottsfield     RF5      24267
Abbottsfield     AP       9745
Abbottsfield     CSC      57799
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT
    p.Neighbourhood,
    p.Zones,
    (CAST(COUNT(p.*) AS FLOAT) / CAST(
        (SELECT
            COUNT(*)
        FROM properties AS p1
        WHERE p1.Neighbourhood=p.Neighbourhood) AS FLOAT)
    ) AS proportion
FROM properties AS p
GROUP BY p.Neighbourhood, p.Zones;
```

(Modified from my answer to my own question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42866723/find-the-proportion-of-each-x-consisting-of-y-in-postgresql/42868248#42868248).)