# Find the proportion of each X consisting of Y in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have a big database of Magic: the Gathering cards and decklists. The table of cards contains the type and converted mana cost of each card (among other things). The decks are stored using two tables: a table of the decks themselves called "decks", and a table called "deckmembers", in which each row contains the ID of a deck, the ID of a card contained in that deck, and the number of copies of that card that appear in the deck.

What I want is a view of this data in which the rows are:

deck: the ID of a deck

cmc: a converted mana cost appearing on at least one card in that deck

proportion: the percentage of the nonland cards in that deck that have that cmc

Or am I better off deriving this data in Python or R or something?

[This question is conceptually similar, but no one has answered it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38302106/how-to-find-the-proportion-of-zones-for-each-neighbourhood-using-psql)

EDIT:

Since you asked, here's some example data:

cards:

```
 id |        name         |    fulltype     | cmc
----+---------------------+-----------------+-----
  1 | "Ach! Hans, Run!"   | Enchantment     |   6
  2 | 1996 World Champion | Summon _ Legend |   5
  4 | AWOL                | Instant         |   3
  5 | Abandon Hope        | Sorcery         |   2
  6 | Abandon Reason      | Instant         |   3
```

decks:

```
 id |      name
----+-----------------
  1 | RDW
  2 | Red Deck Recall
  3 | RDW
  4 | Red Deck Wins
  5 | Red Deck Wins
```

deckmembers:

```
 deck | card  | count
------+-------+-------
    1 | 14031 |     1
    1 | 15011 |     1
    1 | 14263 |     1
    1 | 12966 |     1
    1 | 12536 |     1
```

Any deck will have many cards. Any card may appear in many decks. Each card has an integer from 0-12 associated it which is called its "converted mana cost" or CMC. That's all you need to know. Don't bother learning to play Magic on my account.

And what I want might look something like:

```
 deck | cmc | perc
------+-------+-------
    1 | 1   |  11
    1 | 2   |  11
    1 | 3   |  11
    1 | 4   |  11
    1 | 5   |  11
```

Where "perc" in the first row says that 11 percent of the cards in the deck with with the id 1 have cmc 1.

Comment: Do you mind including a small set of data (just as there's one in the question referred), and maybe show the desired output alongside?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!

```
SELECT
    d.id,
    c.cmc,
    (CAST(SUM(m.count) AS FLOAT) / 
        (SELECT
            CAST(SUM(m1.count) AS FLOAT)
        FROM deckmembers AS m1
        JOIN cards AS c1 ON c1.id=m1.card
        WHERE NOT m1.sideboard
        AND c1.fulltype NOT LIKE '%Land%'
        AND m1.deck=d.id)
    ) * 100 AS perc
FROM deckmembers AS m
JOIN decks AS d ON d.id=m.deck
JOIN cards AS c ON c.id=m.card
WHERE NOT m.sideboard
AND c.fulltype NOT LIKE '%Land%'
GROUP BY d.id, c.cmc;
```

I also posted a solution to the simpler version of the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38302106/how-to-find-the-proportion-of-zones-for-each-neighbourhood-using-psql/42868309#42868309).